# Implementing an address book in iOS app, how to remove duplicate contacts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a method -(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
and when I hit the contact's name, it gets added to a table on the screen, but if i hit the same name again, a duplicate value is added. I have another method that is supposed to display the table of contacts. Here are my methods in full:

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
NSMutableDictionary *contactInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                        initWithObjects:@[@"", @"", @""]
                                        forKeys:@[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"mobileNumber"]];
CFTypeRef generalCFObject;
generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
if (generalCFObject) {
    printf("here");
    [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"firstName"];
    CFRelease(generalCFObject);
}
generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
if (generalCFObject) {
    [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"lastName"];
    CFRelease(generalCFObject);
}
ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef); i++) {
    CFStringRef currentPhoneLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, i);
    CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, i);

    if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"mobileNumber"];
    }

    CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
    CFRelease(currentPhoneValue);
}
CFRelease(phonesRef);


if (_tableData == nil) {
    _tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    printf("there");
}
[_tableData addObject:contactInfoDict];
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"value of number is%@",[contactInfoDict objectForKey:@"mobileNumber"]);
[_picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *contact = _tableData[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [contact[@"firstName"] stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",contact[@"lastName"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = contact[@"mobileNumber"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How would you identify if two contacts are equal (depending on the answer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html might be useful)? How could you use that to check if you should be adding a new contact to your `_tableData` array or if the contact already appears in that collection?

Comment: @Jonah so maybe something along the lines of initializing a new set as a global? variable or a variable within the method peoplepickernavigationcontroller, and when a contact is selected, add it into the set and when im selecting another contact check to see if it's within the set..?

Comment: I see no need for a new variable. You have a collection (`_tableData`) already and you want to avoid adding duplicates to it. So how would you determine if a given `contactInfoDict` is already in that collection or not?

Comment: perhaps a check to see if the dict is already in the tabledata before this line: [_tableData addObject:contactInfoDict];
?

Comment: since tableData is a NSMutableArray, I'd use [myArray containsObject:myObject]; to see if the contactInfoDict is already in the Array right? If not, then add. If it is, do nothing!

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea. You might eventually need to compare `ABRecordID`s instead of checking if the entire `contactInfoDict` is identical but you should be off to a good start.

Comment: why is comparing ABRecordID possibly needed in the end? sorry about the mass of questions, I'm pretty new to iOS :(

Comment: A contact might change over time. It's ID should be constant but what should happen if I add a contact, add a new phone number to that contact, and then try to add it again? Not necessarily an issue for you today but its usually worth considering how you are defining "equal" in a context like this; do you really want identical, equal IDs, or some other rule.